# Time comparison in excel with a 24h time format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

With the following data available for **CutoffTime** and Delivery Time, can you suggest a universal formula that will correctly show the Status as Breached or Not Breached considering the day rollover at `00:00:00`,

| CutoffTime | Delivery Time | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1:30:00 AM | 4:51:33 AM | Breached |
|  | 9:45:30 PM | Not Breached |
|  | 12:30:00 AM | Not Breached |

I tried the following, but it gives an incorrect result for `12:30:00 AM`. It should give Not Breached, but I get Breached.

`=IF(OR(AND(B1<A$1, OR(B1<TIME(12,0,0), B1>=TIMEVALUE("12:00:00 AM"))), AND(B1>A$1, B1<TIME(12,0,0))), "Cutoff Breached", "Cutoff Not Breached")`

Comment: What is condition for `Breached`? Can you explain how `9:45:30 PM` is `Not Breached`? It should be `Breached`?

Comment: `B1>=TIMEVALUE("12:00:00 AM")` is equal to `B1>=0` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

So just the minimum, not checking for blank etc and this simple comparison works:

[image]

```
IF(B2>$A$2,"Breached","Not B")
```

Adding a test to see if B5 is blank:

```
IF(B5="","",IF(B5>$A$2,"Breached","Not B"))
```

Comment: "9:45:30 PM" should be not breached :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout according to the single 24h period it must be breached as it is after 1:30, the only time not breached ie PRIOR to 1:30 is 12:30.

Comment: Look at his screenshot. That is the expected result :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout but if you check the timeline then I think the "expected' result is incorrect twice...

Comment: OP says "I tried the following, but it gives an incorrect result for 12:30:00 AM. It should give Not Breached, but I get Breached.", The screenshot/Excel table is to show expected results. Having said that, maybe my understanding is incorrect :) Let's wait for OP to com eback.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, you can try

`=IF(AND(B2>0,B2<=$A$2),"Not Breached",IF(AND(B2>0.5,B2<=(1+$A$2)),"Not Breached","Breached"))`

[image]